# Issue with Retrieving Coordinates from Firebase to Generate Map Markers

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-maps

My apologies, but I am still fairly new to React Native and my terminology and vocabulary is still rather limited. I am currently trying to generate map markers by fetching data from Firebase. As of now, I am able to retrieve the information with the coordinates in the variable finished; but I am having trouble updating the array of `listingData`. In Debugger mode, it shows that `listingData` is undefined

Also, I am not too sure about the second part of my code, which is suppose to hypothetically call upon the coordinates in `listingData` and then place the markers on the map.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Tam

```
export default class GetMarkers extends Component {  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listingData: []
        }
     }

 componentWillMount(){
    let q = firebase.database().ref('profiles');
    q.on('value', (snap) => {
        var finished = []
        snap.forEach((data) => {
        let result = data.val();
        result["key"] = data.key;
        finished.push(result);
        })
        this.setState({
        listingData: finished
        })
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <MapView>
            {this.state.listingData.map(x => (
              <MapView.Marker
                title={x.fName}
                key={x.key}
                description={'Test'}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: x.lat,
                  longitude: x.lon
                }} />
          ))
        }
        </MapView>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: "_but I am having trouble updating the array of `listingData`._" What is the problem?? Describe what is happening and what did you expect instead. And looks like you have an infinite loop in your component life cycle; since you are calling `setState()` in `componentWillMount()`. Means, everytime your component needs to mount, it will restart the cycle and call `componentWillMount()` all over again, and keeps restarting. Hint: Do that task in your constructor.

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to properly populate `listingData` with the Firebase data stored in local variable `finished`